# Removing Debugger installed Visual Studio 2010 Addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, add-in

I was trying a test project for creating a visual studio addin in C#. 
The addin created some item in the standard toolbar and attached some functionality to it. while I was trying to debug the Addin pressing F5, the VS would launch a new instance of VS with addin showing on the new window of visual studio where I could test and debug my addin.

Now this addin has kind of stick in the toolbar of my visual studio permanenetly (any instance I launch ) and I can not seem to remove it. I have tried tools->Addin manager unticked the addin and restarted VS but the addin does not seem to go away.

Need advice on how to revert what VS might have done to install this adddin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the add-in

1. Delete the .addin XML registration file for the add-in that you want to remove.
   The default location is ..\Users\username\ Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Addins.
2. At a Visual Studio command prompt, type devenv /resetaddin Namespace.ClassName, where Namespace is the name of your add-in project and Classname is its class name, for example, devenv /resetaddin MyAddin1.Connect.

Let me know if that helps...

Comment: Yes I figured out the same in MSDN that was helpful,